# layer hide when type password

Tags: cookies, passwords, hide, layer

I put this layer on all pages on my website(layout) and I want to hide this layer when user type password(hello) using cookie.

I tried to mix two sources but it doesn't work :(
Can you guys help me? thanks :)

--- HTML ---

```
    <div class="popPass">
        <div class="passcode aligncenter">
            <form name="loginpage" action="javascript:;" method="post" onsubmit="return LogIn( this );">
                <div class="input nobottomborder">
                    <div class="inputcontent">
                        <input type="password" id="password" /><br />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="buttons">
                    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Login">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I think I missed something.

Comment: Here's my script https://jsfiddle.net/pzhrjwfo/

Comment: I guess your tags for this question are inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

From your fiddle, you defined your LogIn function inside the jQuery ready callback, which is not in the global scope. So the onsubmit handler can't access it. Try to lift it to the global scope.